# Is it possible for a hacker to point another domain at my domain?

Tags: web-development, security, nginx

Recently when I search my website on google, I find that another domain's description is identical to my domain. I'm terrified and try to understand the security breaches of my website as much as possible. I clicked on the link of this fake website and it turned out to be 'Your connection is not private'. When I search this fake website's domain through whois, it shows another company's info.

My website is built with react, hosted on a VM with docker and nginx.

I found this fake website today, just after I tried implementing google analytics and google tag manager on my website yesterday.

Can you tell me what's going on now please? And how I can prevent any security issues?

My nginx config in default.conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.mywebsite.com; 
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$host$1; 

    location / { 
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    } 
    error_page 404 /index.html;
    location = / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

# nginx docker container, ssl config
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    root html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl.key;   
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    } 
}
```

---

### Now I know I need to setup the default server

###### 80 default server works fine

I'm not going to list it 80 default server here, more see accepted answer.

###### 443 ssl default server, which doesn't work for me :(

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate path-to-pem;
    ssl_certificate_key path-to-key;
    server_name _;

    # Everything is a 404 Not found
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

---

### I still don't know how to setup the 443 ssl default server block for nginx, please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: What is your nginx configuration?   Specifically, do you have a "catch all" block for unrecognized domain names or do you just have one virtual host for your real domain name?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have edited the post now you can see my default.conf for nginx container. Well, I copy this nginx config from some blogs on the Internet and add some features to fit my react website. So, I can hardly understand how nginx works. For virtual host, I only setup one for my domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anybody can point any domain to your web server.   When this happens it is usually not an attack or a security threat.  It is often because some other website used to use your IP address or because some other website is misconfigured.

In your case some other domain is pointing to your server.  Your server is issuing a redirect for that domain from HTTP to HTTPS.  The the HTTPS request fails because the host name doesn't match the SSL certificate.  There are better ways to handle this.

You can use your webserver configuration to show an appropriate error message for unrecognized domain names.  Every HTTP/HTTPS request is made to your server with the host name included as part of the request.  Your webserver can use that information to show an error.

Under Nginx and Apache this is done by configuring an extra "catch all" virtual host to handle unknown domains.   This default catch-all needs to come first in your configuration before the more specific virtual host for your domain name.

To serve a 404 error rather than redirecting unknown domain names to HTTPS you would use configuration like this at the top of nginx's `default.conf`:

```
# The default server:
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;

    # Everything is a 404 Not found
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526996/nginx-how-to-always-return-a-custom-404-page-for-the-default-host which has examples with a custom error document.

Unknown domains will use this virtual host because it is listed first in the file.   Domains that match a specific server_name will use its virtual host.   To that end you should update the `server_name` to something like the following so that the bare domain works as well as ALL subdomains.

```
server_name example.com *.example.com;
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/718801/server-aliases-on-nginx

You could consider using a default virtual host for the `listen 443 ssl` block as well.  That is a bit less important because unknown domains get a certificate error.  Although any client that ignores that error still gets a copy of your site at some other domain.

Comment: This is what I find about nginx catchall block [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454764/nginx-server-name-wildcard-or-catch-all), Can I change 'server_name example.com *.example.com; ' to 'server_name _'?

Comment: In the catch all the server game can be whatever you want. It's very common to use local host or the underscore. The server name in your real virtual host that matches your site needs to have all the host names for which you don't want to show an error document. That should be your bare domain name, the www subdomain, and possibly a wild card subdomain.

Comment: My website works fine when I only set up default server for port 80, but it doesn't work when I setup default server for port 443 with ssl, why is that?

Comment: Here is my 443 ssl default server `# The default server for 443 with ssl on
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate pem-path; 
    ssl_certificate_key key-path;  
    server_name _;

    # Everything is a 404 Not found
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}`

Comment: Any SSL virtual host is going to need all the `ssl_` directives.    I'd also set it up to use a self-signed certificate rather than the real certificate from your site that isn't going to match the host name anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are likely no security breaches on your website.  Their actions would have been done without touching your server.

You may be able to mitigate this by setting up a rule in your server to redirect any unknown domain to your canonical domain. This looks like is already happening for http, but not for https - which is a little harder, as it needs to be conditional (ie if domain name us not the preferred one  rewrite it to that).  You can alternatively do it in software.

It is somewhat concerning that they can do this at all - indeed there is little you can do to stop them cloning a static version if your site - although the question I can only speculate to is "why are they doing this"?

I speculate (Not guaranteed to help - but a good practice anyway)  might be to add Google analytics or similar to yourvsite and also to ensure GMB (goole my business) is up to date and knows the legit versiin if your website.  In this way you may be helping Google know the correct canonical version of your site - so that if/when the shadow site is pointed elsewhere it does not cause you credibility issues.